# cant insert new child in correct position using eq() in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i have a `table` as follows

```
<table id="selectable">
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default "></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default "></td>
        <!---here i want to add 1 td-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!---here i want to add 1 td-->
        <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
        <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in `first row` i have to add one `td` as `3rd coloumn` and in `second row` i have to add 1 td as `first coloumn.`

for this i have the following code

```
var addTd = function() {
   $( "td", $container ).eq(2).before(what);
   $( "td", $container ).eq(5).before(what);
}
```

but this code add i `td`  `not in first row` but in `second row` as first `coloumn` ,and 1 `td` in `3rd row` as `first coloumn`

Comment: `.eq()` is zero-based. `eq(2)` selects the third element.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are going to be always first and last maybe better easier to just use .append / .appendTo and .prepend / .prependTo

```
var addTd = function() {

    $( "tr:nth-child(0)", $container ).append( what );
    $( "tr:nth-child(1)", $container ).prepend( what );

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this documentation about [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/),

> Given a single `<ul>` containing two `<li>`s, $( "li:nth-child(1)" )
>   selects the first `<li>` while  $( "li:eq(1)" ) selects the second.

It should be like this:

```
$( "td:eq(1)" ).after('<td class="ui-state-default">qwe</td>');
$( "td:eq(3)" ).before('<td class="ui-state-default">qwe</td>');
```